# Customize related field in Django model specifying foreign keys to relate through

Tags: python, django, foreign-key-relationship, django-custom-manager

In my Django project I have a model for products that look like this:

```
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Product(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer')
    # .favorite_set: ManyToOne relation coming from the
    # 'Favorite' class (shown a couple of lines below)
```

My site's *User*(s) can mark some products as *Favorite*. To provide this functionality, I have a Django model that looks like this:

```
class Favorite(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'product',)
```

In that model, the `.product` ForeignKey creates a reverse relation in the `Product` model called `favorite_set`. That's all good and useful: When I get an HTTP request from a user to retrieve products, I can easily figure out whether it's been favorited by a particular user or not by doing this:

```
product = Product.objects.get(id='whatever_id')
is_favorited = bool(product.favorite_set.filter(user=self.user).count() == 1)
# or probably:
#   is_favorited = product.favorite_set.filter(user=self.user).exists()
#
```

Now, I have another model that is **heavily denormalized** (SQL denormalized, that is) that I want to use for fast text searches.

This model "pretends" to be a Product, but includes data found through the "regular" Product's FK relationships into the model itself. Something like this:

```
class ProductSearch(models.Model):
    product = models.OneToOneField('Product', 
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                   related_name='searcher')
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

This class has its own `id` field (since it's a Django model) and, as you can see above, it is going to have a `OneToOne` relationship to the products (one of this `ProductSearch` entries is linked to one and only one `Product`)

Thanks to this model, if I want to search products whose manufacturer is *"Ford"* (for example), I don't need to join the `Product` table with the `Manufacturer`'s table. I can do the lookup directly in `ProductSearch` and save a few milliseconds.

Since the `ProductSearch` is intended to be compatible with a `Product`, I'm also trying to model the `favorite_set` that occurs "naturally" in my `Product` class into this `ProductSearch` model.

And that's where the difficulties arise: I don't know how to do that **:-)**

I ideally would have something like:

```
class ProductSearch(models.Model):
    product = models.OneToOneField('Product', 
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                   related_name='searcher')
    manufacturer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    #
    # Couldn't find anything to do the following:
    product_favorite_set = models.ManyToOneField('Favorite',
                                                 through_fields=('product',))
```

But I haven't been able to do that.

I have tried to "abuse" the `ManyToManyField` like this:

```
class ProductSearch(BaseModel):
    product = models.OneToOneField('Product', 
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                   related_name='searcher')
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product_favorite_set = models.ManyToManyField('Favorite', related_name='+',
                                              through='Favorite',
                                              through_fields=['product']
                                              )
```

But that produces an error on System Check:

```
api.Favorite: (fields.E336) The model is used as an intermediate model
              by 'api.ProductSearch.product_favorite_set', but it
              does not have a foreign key to 'ProductSearch' or 'Favorite'.
api.ProductSearch.product_favorite_set: (fields.E339) 'Favorite.product'
              is not a foreign key to 'ProductSearch'.
```

I imagine I could make the `product_favorite_set` a Python `@property`, and then do a custom query in it like:

```
class ProductSearch(BaseModel):
     # ....
     @property
     def product_favorite_set(self):
           return Favorite.objects.filter(product=self.product)
```

But I would like to know if I can do this using "pure" Django tools (only if out of curiosity)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You dont need to model the relationship. For an instance `ps` of `ProductSearch` :  `ps.product.favorite_set` is available to you.

Comment: @ShikharChauhan thank you for your comment. However, that `ps.product.favorite_set` is going to produce a _join_ between `ProductSearch` and `Product`, which is something I wanted to avoid (for performance purposes)

Comment: ProductSearch instance points to a product instance which in turn has a favorite_set , so you dont need to specify it explicitly. If you print the query django uses for this lookup , you'll see that the tables are being `joined`

Comment: Sorry.. Ha ha.. I saw your edit after I posted my comment, so I edited it in turn :)

Comment: Given proper indexing, joins are not a problem.